# How to fetch Real values from model as decimals (doubles) in Z3 (Java)?

Tags: java, z3

I'm trying to fetch Real values from a `Model` computed by a `Solver`. However, even though I've set pp.decimal to true (both in the SMT2 file and using the `Global.setParameter`), that's only obeyed when printing the model itself.

When I attempt to fetch values by using `model.getConstInterp` over the values of `model.getConstDecls`, they all display fractions (making my hacky solution of using `Double.parseDouble` infeasible).

I was wondering if there's any convenient way to fetch the values of constant functions within the model without forcing me to write a parser (for either the model or the arithmetic expressions it's producing).

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT to include example:

```
BoolExpr[] assertions = ctx.parseSMTLIB2String(smt, null, null, null, null);

// get solver from context (modelled upon assertions)
Solver solver = ctx.mkSolver();
solver.add(assertions);

switch (solver.check()) {
    case SATISFIABLE: {
        // fetch our model
        Model model = solver.getModel();
        System.out.println(model);

        for(FuncDecl constant : model.getConstDecls()) {
            // get the interpretation
            Expr value = model.getConstInterp(constant);
            System.out.println(value.toString());
```

Output:

```
(define-fun b () Real
  (- 1.0))
(define-fun w2 () Real
  0.5)
(define-fun w1 () Real
  0.5)
-1
1/2
1/2
```

I'm looking to somehow extract the results of these constant functions into Java `double`s. I could simply parse the values of the `Expr`s' `toString()` if they would both abide by `pp.decimal`.

Comment: StackOverflow works best if you can post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It should show the output you're getting and what you were expecting or hoping to get.

Comment: I've edited the question to include example code @LeventErkok

Answer (score 3):

After light digging (beyond the scope of looking at autocomplete suggestions), I worked out that you can simply check if the `Expr` you have is a `RatNum`. From there, you can up-cast to a `RatNum` and use `getNumerator` and `getDenominator()` and yield a `double` from division that way.

```
Expr value = model.getConstInterp(constant);
if(value.isRatNum()) {
    RatNum rational = (RatNum) value;
    IntNum num = rational.getNumerator(), den = rational.getDenominator();
    System.out.println("Value = " + ((double) num.getInt() / den.getInt()));
}
```

This makes sense now.

Comment: If this works for you, great! But keep in mind that dividing two integers to give you a double will be subject to rounding errors and will not capture the true "real" value; but I guess you cannot avoid that. Also, Z3 `Real` values are actually algebraic reals (i.e., roots of polynomials), so those are out of reach as well.